# Query that uses the Aggregate extension method against DbContext

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, aggregate-functions, expression-trees

I had a `MockDataStore` that returns a `List<Task>`. Then I would use the `Aggregate` extension method to query that list. So I was doing a LINQ-to-Objects query which does the job quiet nicely. Now that I've replaced my mock data store with a class that inherits the `DbContext` class, the same query does not work anymore because I cannot use a lambda expression that has a body since it cannot be converted to an expression tree. So is there a way to get around it and still have the aggregation done in SQL and avoid having to do it in-memory? Below is my code:

```
        //List<Task> tasks = MockDataStore.GetData()
        //    .Aggregate(new List<Task>(), (accumulator, treaty) => { accumulator.AddRange(treaty.Tasks); return accumulator; })
        //    .Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Equals(companyId) && x.StatusId == statusId).ToList();

        using (SCGREDbContext context = new SCGREDbContext())
        {
            List<Task> tasks = context.Treaties.Aggregate(new List<Task>(), (accumulator, treaty) => { accumulator.AddRange(treaty.Tasks); return accumulator; })
                                .Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Equals(companyId) && x.StatusId == statusId).ToList();
            return tasks;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why exactly are you using `Aggregate()`? I think your `Aggregate()` call is equivalent to this call to [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
context.Treaties.SelectMany(treaty => treaty.Tasks)
```

Comment: Great! Now I finally how understand what `SelectMany` is used for :)